# How to query Sidekiq queues by Job class, queue name and arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have to check if the same job has already been added to the queue before enqueue again.

Currently I use this code but it's very inefficient because it loads all object into memory. Is there a way to query like a normal active record?

Ideally, I would something like

```
Sidekiq::Queue.where(job_class: "SyncJob", queue_name:"high", arguments: [1,2,3])
```

Current code:

```
def list_queued_jobs(job_class, queue_name,  arguments)
  found_jobs = []
  queues = Sidekiq::Queue.all
  queues.each do |queue|
    queue.each do |job|
      job.args.each do |arg|
        if arg['job_class'].to_s == job_class.to_s && arg['queue_name'] == queue_name && ActiveJob::Arguments.deserialize(arg['arguments']) == arguments
          found_jobs << job
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return found_jobs
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution, but there is a simpler way to determine if a job's been already queued (`true`/`false`):

```
def in_queues?(job_class, queue_name,  arguments = [])
  Sidekiq::Queue.new(queue_name).any? do |job|
    job_class == job.klass && job.args == arguments
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that sidekiq arguments are presented as an array. For example, if you call your job like:

```
SyncJob.perform_async([1, 2, 3])
```

then you check that it's been queued as follows:

```
in_queues?("SyncJob", "high", [[1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you! It's very fast! I've just made this change inside the block to make it work 
job['wrapped'].to_s == job_class.to_s && ActiveJob::Arguments.deserialize(job.args[0]['arguments']) == arguments

Comment: @sparkle: yes, i ve made a typo, it should have been `klass` instead of `class`) but `args` seems to work fine without deserializing on my local machine

Comment: klass is "ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper" while job['wrapped'] is "SyncJob"

Comment: ahh, I see, you are using it together with activejob wrappers, while i ve been testing it with plain Sidekiq setup) anyway, i'm glad it's worked!

Answer (score 1):

Checking for an existing job is known as "unique jobs". Sidekiq Enterprise provides this functionality, as do several 3rd party gems.

Implementing and using the code you describe is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: Why is it a very bad idea?

Comment: See "Usage and Warning" https://www.mikeperham.com/2021/04/20/a-tour-of-the-sidekiq-api/